# How do you observe changes to Magento data?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I would like to observe changes to almost all Magento store data (e.g. customers, orders, products).  The SOAP/RPC API does not appear to be able to get a list of changes of data.

Is the only way to build a module that observes most of the Magento events found here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events?

Comment: Mostly it yeah... Or add triggers to every one of it's tables (oh yeah, key value stores / eav, and then split on type... Great Idea!), although that might only be useful if you only want to know _which_ items / records changed, not _what_ propery changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `model_save_before` / `model_save_after`

But, there's not guarantee that this will catch all write operations affecting an entity. It's possible to insert / change / delete entity data using the write adapter, bypassing the ORM and the framework entirely.

The important question is: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I wanted to send orders to a fulfillment company.  Appears no good way to incrementally extract data.

Comment: Always a custom space. Depends on what you need to send, when it needs to send, and what if any inputs from them you need. Have you looked into [uDropship](http://www.unirgy.com/products/udropship/)?

Comment: I need something custom.  Looks like only a pull with a custom API will really suffice.

Comment: @CarsonReinke correct me if i'm wrong but if you are sending order detail to a fulfillment company, shouldn't these be the only events that would affect fulfillment  'order place', 'order/items invoiced' and/or 'order/items canceled'?

Comment: @R.S, sounds like it, depends on either a pull or a push.  I was looking for a simpler CRUD, but the specific events work too.